# Join_all using plyr does not work with type="full"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a file list that I would like to join, but the function does not accept type="full", only type="left". Anyone experenced similar problems?

```
datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F,sep = "\t")})

joined <- full_join(dfs = datalist,by = "V1",type="full",match="all")
```

Using `type="full"` it does not join anything, only print the first datafile

Comment: I think you are mixing up `plyr::join_all` and `dplyr::full_join`.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) for a possible duplicate.

Comment: No,  dont think so. join_all should have a type="full" parameter

Comment: Yeah look at your code, it says `full_join`, not `join_all`....... You only have `join_all` in your title. Also your title mentions `plyr`, but your question is tagged `dplyr`.